# Abrir LINK oculto em nova aba com javascript

Tags: javascript

Através do StackOverflow eu consegui um código que estava buscando, que serve para ocultar o link de destino, para não aparecer ao apontar o mouse sobre a imagem ou vídeo que tem o link, mas agora eu preciso que, ao clicar, abra numa nova guia, e não saia do meu blog.

O Código é o seguinte:

```
<div onclick="javascript:window.location.href = 'http://www.sonoticias8515.com.br/canal/canal/votacao-melhor-gol-da-uefa-champions-league---golaco-do-barcelona-jogo:-barcelona-/2507811a1k5s9h3551638010852a21510855 ';" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;">Teste</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando usas `window.location.href` estás a abrir um novo url na mesma página. Uma vez que não é isso que queres deves usar o [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Nesse caso podes usar algo como

```
<div onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.o.url.que.queres', '_blank');" ...
```

Mas parece-me que estás a passar ao lado da solução mais fácil. Se não queres que o mouse mude em cima de um link normal (`<a href="...">Link</a>`)  podes fazer isso com CSS assim: (**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umtLvc2f/)**).

CSS:

```
a.nostyle:link {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: default;
}

a.nostyle:visited {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: default;
}
```

E no link/âncora só precisas de adicionar a classe `nostyle`.

Comment: Muito bom Sérgio, resolveu meu problema cara, quanto ao CSS eu não precisei, com o código acima e implementando com o seu código window.open eu consegui ocultar o link e quando clicarem ele agora está abrindo em nova aba. Parabéns e muito obrigado!

Comment: @MarcosSantos eu sei que o código iria funcionar o que eu queria dizer é que podes fazer o mesmo com CSS e usando âncoras (`<a>`). Seria melhor do ponto de vista da funcionalidade, semântica e SEO. Mas usa como te sentires mais confiante.